# 0-1 Knapsack implementation yielding wrong answer

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I've added my implementation of both recursive and DP of knapsack problem. I couldn't find the error in it. Kindly help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Knapsac {

    static int[][] dp;

    static int knapsack(int[] size,int[] value, int i, int weight){
        if(i <= 0)
            return 0;
        if(weight < 0)
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        if(dp[weight][i] != -1)
            return dp[weight][i];

        dp[weight][i] = Math.max(knapsack(size, value, i-1, weight - size[i]) + value[i], knapsack(size, value, i-1, weight));
        return dp[weight][i];
    }

    static int knapsackWithoutDP(int[] size, int[] value, int i, int weight){
        if(i <= 0)
            return 0;
        if(weight < 0)
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        return Math.max(knapsackWithoutDP(size, value, i-1, weight - size[i]) + value[i], knapsackWithoutDP(size, value, i-1, weight));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int W, n;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        W = in.nextInt(); n = in.nextInt();
        dp = new int[W+1][n];

        for(int i = 0; i < W+1; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                dp[i][j] = -1;


        int[] size = new int[n], value = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            size[i] = in.nextInt();
            value[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println(knapsackWithoutDP(size, value, size.length-1,  W));
        System.out.println(knapsack(size, value, size.length-1,  W));
    }

}
```

I am working with the test case

```
4 5
1 8
2 4
3 0
2 5
2 3
```

I should be getting 13 for both but am getting 12.

Can someone help me to understand the error in my implementation?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be you cannot choose the first element of your subset:

```
if(i <= 0)
     return 0;
```

But this means you cannot reach the point where you choose if you want to include or exclude the item whom index is `0`, which is the first element you can choose. (value[0],weight[0] is a valid choice to be added to your knapsack)

Quick fix is to simply change this stop clause to

```
if(i < 0) //strictly smaller than
     return 0;
```

Comment: That gives me 17. The right answer is 13. I had tried that before, but kept this way because this gave me a closer answer

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, I had to change weight < 0 to weight < 1, because bag had least capacity of 1.